# WPF calling method in usercontrol from window

Tags: wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

Im creating a WPF app using Caliburn Micro!

I have a window with a menu - lets say they are called A, B, C

Underneath I have a usercontrol that shows a mainView or different usercontrols if 'B' or 'C' is pressed - that part is working fine!

My problem is that I want to call a method in the mainView usercontrol when pressing 'A' in the Menu window.

---

Is that possible ???

Comment: It would be great if you could share samples of your code.

Answer (score 0):

I got it!

I must have been tired!
I tried to call the method from a different instance of the ViewModel than the one that loaded the page!